# CollabNet Subversion Edge user migration

Tags: ldap, user-accounts, subversion-edge

Is there any way to migrate user accounts to a new server in CollabNet's Subversion Edge? I've read that you can't just copy the [CSVN_HOME]/data/conf/svn_auth_file because it won't create the accounts for the users due to the one-way hash for Apache passwords. Isn't this because the file is written in two places? If I can find the location of this other file, then I could just copy the two files over and it should work, right?
Otherwise, using LDAP seems to be the method of choice for migrating accounts, but the question is how to setup and configure LDAP? I apologize; I'm very new to servers, version control, and LDAP. Any help and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LDAP is an option, that is the best way to go as users do not need a second password to manage.  This only makes sense if you have an existing LDAP Server like Windows Active Directory that you can connect to.  Configuring LDAP can be tricky because its syntax is fairly obtuse, especially if you are not used to working with it.  The [Subversion Edge FAQ](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#section-FrequentlyAskedQuestions-LDAPQuestions) has a section on LDAP that gives the tips as best we can.  You generally are going to need access to the directory server or an admin that has access in order to get the LDAP "Distinguished Names" (DN) that you need for configuration.

Subversion Edge has a [wiki page on migration](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/MigrationPath) that discusses migrating users from an Apache password file and what your options are.

Good luck, I would encourage follow-up questions in the [Subversion Edge discussion forum](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/discussion/do/listTopics/projects.svnedge/discussion.user_questions).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I will check out those references and hopefully get LDAP configured soon.